# How can i find whether it is a text box or text area using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I find whether an element is a text box or text area using jQuery?

For example i am having two radio button:

> While i clicking the first one it should display text box.
>
> While i clicking the second one it should display text area.
>
> But nearby text box label should be displayed "TEXTBOX" using jquery.
>
> And nearby textarea label should be displayed "TEXAREA" using jquery.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#text').is("textarea")
$('#text').is("input")
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(controlId).type` will give you the type of the dom Element.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w2xAT/)